# Logarithmic inequality calculation

Tags: inequality, logarithms, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Find least integral value of n such that
$$\left(\frac{\root \of 5+1}{2}\right)^n > 100$$

I want to solve this without the use of a calculator or logarithmic tables.
I tried using AM-GM, such that the "lesser than" side is equal to $100$.
$$\left(\frac{\root \of 5+1}{2}\right)^n > 5^{\frac{n}{4}}$$
Now $5^\frac{n}{4} = 100$.
Again, same issue, I am unable to solve this without log tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a slightly entertaining way to do it - perhaps not what's intended!

Binet's formula says that the $n$th Fibonnaci number is given by

$$F_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\varphi^n - \psi^n)$$ where

$\varphi = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \sqrt{5})$ and $\psi = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Since $|\psi| < 1$, we can approximate $F_n \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \varphi^n$, with an error $< 1$.

So we're reduced to finding the least $n$ such that $F_n > 100/\sqrt{5}$, which is about $45$, again to the nearest integer. This is then an easy task - $n = 10$.

Comment: You can avoid the $\sqrt5$ in the denominator question by letting $G_n=\phi^n+\psi^n$ and get $G_0=2,G_1=1$ and $G_{n+2}=G_{n+1}+G_n,$ or $G_n=2F_{n+1}-F_n=F_{n+1}+F_{n-1}.$ You still have to deal, in the general case when solving $G_n>M$ with the fact $\psi<0,$ so that if $G_n=M,$ it depends on whether $n$ is even or odd, but there is no such $n$ when $M=100.$

Answer (score 3):

The interesting thing here is you have the golden ratio, $\newcommand{\p}{\varphi} \p$. It satisfies the identity
$$
\p^2 = \p+1
$$
and hence
$$\begin{align*}
\p^3 &= \p^2 + \p = 2\p+1 \\
\p^4 &= 2\p^2 + \p = 2(\p+1)+\p = 3\p+2 \\
\p^5 &= 3\p^2 + 2\p = 3(\p+1)+2\p  = 5\p + 3
\end{align*}$$
and so on. One could naturally extrapolate this to a pattern of
$$
\p^n = F_n \p + F_{n-1}
$$
for $F_n$ the $n$th Fibonacci number.

It is then easy to proceed by exhaustion, really. One sees that
$$
\p^9 =  34 \p + 21 \qquad
\p^{10} = 55\p+34
$$
One could use a crude approximation of $\p$, say $\p \approx 1.618$, to comfortably conclude that the $n$ desired is $10$.